# sql connection from visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have an asp.net website that I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database but I keep getting the error shown below. I am developing in Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

[image]

Comment: It can be a lot of things. Is that server name ok? Is it running? is it configured for remote connections?

Comment: Please just quote the error message, rather than posting a gigantic screenshot of it.  It's more searchable, and much easier to read.

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider:Named Pipes Provider , error:40_could not open a connection to SQL Server

Comment: I have configured to allow remote connections